# I'm getting an "Access is Denied" error when I try to open an HTML file with chrome using the sublime text build system

Tags: html, sublimetext3

Sublime Text's build system refuses to open an html file with chrome.

My build system, named "html.sublime-build" looks like this:

```
{
   "cmd": ["\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe\"", "$file"]
}
```

I've also tried escaping backslashes:

```
{
   "cmd": ["\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\"", "$file"]
}
```

But instead of launching chrome it says: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Comment: If you use `cmd`, then internally the Python `subprocess` module tries to execute the first argument as a program (`shell_cmd` passes the command to the shell to process). So, I'd try it without adding the `\"` quoted double quotes around the name of the program in the first argument.

Comment: @OdatNurd Yup, the `\"` was the problem thank you, I wish you had written it as an answer instead of a comment, I would have accepted it.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! I didn't have time to test locally before I answered (I was on hold for a meeting at the time). Pretty sure you can accept your own answer if you want to do it yourself, though.